# Hierarchical layout with vis.js

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I'm using `vis.js` library to graphically display a network. I read the documentation and I need to use the hierarchical layout. It works fine until I use the `sortMethod='directed'` option. In this case I end up with a blank page. There's no Javascript error. Every other options combination works fine, but I need the `directed` option. I followed the documentation and it doesn't seem that I need to add further information to the network: it should all work with the *'from'* and *'to'* edges properties. What could it be?
Thank you all.

Comment: I am also having this problem in 4.12.0. The blank page seems to occur when there is a node that has no edges going either in or out. If all nodes are connected things work OK.

I have not tested extensively and am not sure if there are additional conditions under which the blank page occurs with no console errors.

Comment: @DevonHolcombe I checked, it happens even when all nodes are connected.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug. I have been using this feature for months and suddenly it stopped working. I get the same behaviour as the one you describe. All options seem to work except the sortMethod='directed'. I cannot tell for sure which version introduced this bug but I found it out at 4.12.0.

We probably need to raise an issue to let their dev team know about it.
Hope that helps. It is not exactly a solution to your issue but rather a verification of this bug since I have the same issue.

EDIT:

I tried both 4.11.0 and 4.10.0

4.11.0 : I get the same buggy behaviour.

4.10.0 : Works as expected. No issues.

Comment: I'm gonna do that, thanks for the feedback. I'll keep this post updated.